# How to create delegate of Func<a,b> when a's method has parameters

Tags: c#, function, reflection, delegates

I am trying to call a method that takes in a function, but using relection. I've gotten it to work when the method is parameterless but I can't figure out how to invoke it when there are arguments. This is a contrived simplified example, but this boils down the problem. I will not know the arguments to Add until runtime.

Any pointers? Do I have to use expression trees? Is there an easier way to do this?

```
public void Main()
{
    //works
    CallFunction(typeof (Processor), "Count");
    //I don't understand what I need to modify to make add work
    CallFunction(typeof (Processor), "Add");
}

public void CallFunction(Type type, string methodToCall)
{
    var targetMethod = type.GetMethod(methodToCall);
    var constructedType = typeof (MethodCaller<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    dynamic target = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType);
    var method = constructedType.GetMethod("Do").MakeGenericMethod(targetMethod.ReturnType);
    var func =  typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, targetMethod.ReturnType);
    var toCall = Delegate.CreateDelegate(func, targetMethod);
    method.Invoke(target, new object[] { toCall });
}

public class Processor
{
    public int Count()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public int Add(int toAdd)
    {
        return 1 + toAdd;
    }
}

public class MethodCaller<TParm> where TParm : new()
{
    public TResult Do<TResult>(Func<TParm, TResult> func)
    {
        return func(new TParm());
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need an appropriate version of Func (with appropriate number of generic parameters) and know those parameter's types. The rest of your code can stay roughly the same. No expression trees necessary

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic if I don't know how many parameters Add had, how could i specify Func<,,,,(N commas)> . Also whether processor had a method 
    Multiply(int x, int y)
it doesn't really change the number of parameters for Do, it just takes in a single function of Processor?

Comment: how do you intend to call it then?

Comment: I will know the number of parameters and their values at runtime, but typeof(func<>) is a compile time constant

Comment: Yeah. In that case you may need lots of ifs or a dictionary to do the mapping

Comment: Let me guess, your main intent is to create instances of `MethodCaller<X>` and delegates `Func<X,TRez>` and use them later somehow? Or only purpose of `MethodCaller` is to execute additional code only from `CallFunction` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `type.InvokeMember(method_name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, type_instance, new object[] { param1, param2, param3 });` ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx

Actually whole `CallFunction` method can be simplified like this:

```
public void CallFunction(Type type, string methodToCall, params object[] args)
{
    // Why this part is so complex? Do I miss something?
    //var constructedType = typeof (MethodCaller<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    //dynamic target = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType);

    var target = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var result = type.InvokeMember(method_name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, target, args);
    // ... do something with result if you need ...
}
```

---

If you need `MethodCaller.Do`, but can sacrifice types on signature (or some performance on boxing/unboxing for `DoTyped`)

```
public void CallFunction(Type type, string methodToCall, params object[] args)
{
    var delegate_wrapper = new Func<object, object>(
        instance => type.InvokeMember(methodToCall, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, args)
        );
    var target_method = type.GetMethod(methodToCall);

    var mc_custom_type = typeof (MethodCaller<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var mc_instance = Activator.CreateInstance(mc_custom_type);
    var mc_custom_method = mc_custom_type.GetMethod("Do").MakeGenericMethod(target_method.ReturnType);

    mc_custom_method.Invoke(mc_instance, new object[] { delegate_wrapper });
}

public class MethodCaller<TParm> where TParm : new()
{
    public TResult DoTyped<TResult>(Func<TParm, TResult> func)
    {
        return Do<TResult>(oinstance=>func((TParm)oinstance));
    }

    public TResult Do<TResult>(Func<object, object> func)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I AM DO");
        return (TResult)func(new TParm());
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work on this very simple example but imagine if my do method was doing something more interesting and I needed it to be called

Comment: Yes, I've already found what I'm missing. Pretty interesting question, actually, between tons of homeworks :)

Comment: Well this wasn't exactly the answer to the question I asked but it works! I didn't really think of not even trying to do the typing in the reflected code, but rather just add a helper method to MethodCaller.
Ultimately what I was actually trying to accomplish here is basically create a supped up wcftestclient. My MethodCaller contains the logic to create channel and endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at Impromptu framework. It is primarily for duck typing but the library provide rather slick api to access methods and pass arguments.

https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding